# How to extract only date part from datetime in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

How to extract only date part from datetime in JOOQ?

Example  : Input : 2019-11-14 19:46:45.51 
           Output: 2019-11-14

Answer (score 2):

The results may be vendor specific to some part, but in most SQL dialects, you can just simply cast the `TIMESTAMP` type to a `DATE` type. In SQL:

```sql
CAST(tab.my_timestamp AS DATE)
```

In jOOQ

```java
DSL.cast(TAB.MY_TIMESTAMP, SQLDataType.DATE)
```